# How solve GROUP BY column null priority?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to select elements and then display them using a "`group by`" but I get as result `id_mobilier = null` while I would like to have `id_mobilier = 3` in priority.

How do I display on priority `id_mobilier = 3 and not NULL`

Here is my sql request :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM couleurs 
  LEFT 
  JOIN mobilier_couleurs 
    ON couleurs.id = mobilier_couleurs.id_couleur 
 WHERE id_mobilier IS NULL 
    OR id_mobilier = 3
```

First I got this :

[image]

And if I add `GROUP BY nom` to my request, I got this :

[image]

I want INT in column id_mobilier if exist and not null

Comment: Please add sample input data and then show us the output you want, along with an explanation of the logic you are using.  Note that just adding `GROUP BY` to your current `SELECT *` query is not really valid.

Comment: Rest assured, if you didn't have a problem, you wouldn't be here.

Comment: Step 1: What is your query?
Step 2: What is your result?
Step 3: What you expect result?
This information can help us - help you :)

Comment: Look my screen I need to change the priority of the column id_mobilier i want 3 when I use GROUP BY nom and not NULL

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: How about `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: ORDER BY don't remove the double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM couleurs c LEFT JOIN
     mobilier_couleurs mc
     ON c.id = mc.id_couleur AND mc.id_mobilier = 3;
```

A `GROUP BY` should not be needed, if you just want to see `3` if a row exists and `NULL` if there is no `3`.